# How Do I Prevent Blank Data from being Inserted into a MySQL Table?

Tags: php, mysql, database

***Also malicious inserts***

I've seen this question asked but none of the responses worked for me (or rather I was too stupid to make them work).  I think I need personalized help.  Every time I refresh my php page it inserts blank data.  How do I prevent blank and/or malicious data from being inserted.

This is my code:

```
 <?php

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass") or die ("Couldn't connect!");
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("streams") or die ("Couldn't find db");

    $sql="INSERT INTO streams (streamname)
    VALUES ('$_POST[streamname]')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    echo "1 record added";


    mysql_close($con)

?>

<form action="submit.php" method="POST">
    Stream Name: <input type="text" name="streamname" id="streamname" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Stream" />
</form>
```

Comment: you didnt't validate $_POST[streamname]. By "blank data" you mean '' or NULL ?

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: @SLaks How do I protect from that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap it with some defensive logic:

```
if(!empty($_POST['streamname'])) {

    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: also, if someone enters an empty value, you should give them a warning message stating that it is a required field so they understand why the form will not submit.

Comment: That wraps the entirety of the php from the mysql open to close?

Answer (score 2):

Try checking if POST params are set :

```
 <?php

if($_POST) {

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass") or die ("Couldn't connect!");
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("streams") or die ("Couldn't find db");

    $sql="INSERT INTO streams (streamname)
    VALUES ('$_POST[streamname]')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    echo "1 record added";


    mysql_close($con);
}

?>

<form action="submit.php" method="POST">
    Stream Name: <input type="text" name="streamname" id="streamname" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Stream" />
</form>
```

Comment: just because the post params are set, doesn't mean they won't be blank.

Answer (score 0):

You should be escaping the input.

```
$sql='INSERT INTO streams (streamname)
VALUES ("'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[streamname]).'")';
```

Comment: while important, this is a comment rather than an answer to the question.

Comment: I think it's probably a fix since the array reference is used properly in the insert in this statement.

Comment: @amccausl What does an escape string do?

Comment: It will remove the potential for a [sql injection attach](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html)

Comment: @amccausl I edited my code with what you gave me.  But it seems to have messed up some of my other code.  Now when I make a call to the database instead of saying something like: hi my name is "data".  it says hi my name is "mysql escape (data)".

Comment: you have the function call in the quotes for the string.  try copying the whole line.

Comment: @amccausl Ahh!  It worked!  Is there anyway I cant test that this protects or is it just assumed?