# wordpress custom form to database

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

I'm trying to create a custom submit form on wordpress
I'm using the wp page template from the twentyfourteen theme and put my code inside of the

```
<div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

$wpdb->insert('wp_table',array (
                    'db_column' => $inputtext,
                    )
                );
```

It works, but every time the page loads, it also submit blank data into my wp_table.
how to avoid this? I just want to input data using the submit button.

Comment: You would need to check to see if values are blank. If they aren't then do nothing, else insert the data to the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid submitting blank data into the wordpress table by using `isset` in php

```
if(!empty($_POST['streamname'])) {

// the code
}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797208/how-do-i-prevent-blank-data-from-being-inserted-into-a-mysql-table) one ..Hope it was helpful

Answer (score 2):

```
if( count($_POST) ){
         $wpdb->insert('wp_table',array (
                'db_column' => $inputtext,
                )
            );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before submitting your data, you must make sure it is not empty.
This is the right way to go:

```
if(!empty($_POST['datakey'])) {
    $wpdb->insert('wp_table',array (
                'db_column' => $inputtext,
                )
            );
}
```

This code snippet is commonly seen in Wordpress plugins or themes.